# Way, to enforce upgrade of iphone-app inside app-store?

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store

When releasing multiple versions of an iphone-app, there are problems:

- you are running very old apps (still need to support them through server-api)
- you have to live with bugs of a certain app, once released blocker-bugs are not fixable

Is there a way to mark an iphone-app as unsupported or enforce an online-update, i.e. when it starts up it will show an upgrade button?

So far I always read that you cannot enforce an upgrade of an iphone-app. Is this correct, can somebody give me official reference/link for that? I just cannot believe that once you released an iphone-app this is for eternity? An "unsupported" marker would be a very helpful app-store feature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not enforce app upgrade, but you can add a mecanism in your app to display a message to say that the version is not compatible with server-api. Of course it should be provide on the first app version...

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame that such an app-lifecycle feature is not part of app-store. We already have a status api-call. I will enhance it to give information back 'ok' vs. 'unsupported'.

Comment: Apple is not responsible of external API !